# Default states in ui-router

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on a web development project and I am having a problem in implementing *UI-router* (**AngularJS**).

I want to set a default state when the page loads and also default state for the child view.

If I use `abstract:true` method that is not the solution because when I want to again active that state it won't be possible.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this will give you answer to your Question

```
var App = angular.module('TechdefeatApp',['ui.router']);
App.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    // For any unmatched url, send to /business
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")

    $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/components/home/homeView.html",
        controller:"homeController"
    })
    .state('member', {
        url: "/member/:seo_url",
        templateUrl: "app/components/member/memberView.html",
        controller:"memberController"
    })
    .state('category', {
        url: "/category/:seo_url", 
        templateUrl: "app/components/category/categoryView.html",
        controller:"categoryController"
    })

}]);
```

Comment: yes, I did the same. It works fine for the parent default state, but I want to set default state of the child too. For ex. when I click on member button a view is created and in that view, there are more buttons that open a nested view. How to set that default nested state(For all states)?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use at $urlRouterProvider service,
first inject this service, after that write 
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise')`.

Pay attention that  the /otherwise url must be defined on a state as usual:

`$stateProvider
    .state("otherwise", { url : '/otherwise'...})`

good luck!